# How do I set NODE_OPTIONS in Amplify YAML?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, yaml, http-headers, aws-amplify

I have a NextJS application deployed on Amplify and I'd like to modify the NODE_OPTIONS.

Currently I have been running `NODE_OPTIONS=--max-http-header-size=64555 next dev` locally when running `npm run start`

My question is, how do I add this to the Amplify YAML?

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - env | grep -e NEXT_PUBLIC_ >> .env.production
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: .next
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to AWS Console -> Amplify -> (your app) -> Build Settings.
The 'build settings' option is in the "App Settings" menu options on the left of the webpage. Copy the build settings, then create the `amplify.yml` file in your project's root directory and past the build settings into it.

Deploy your project and those build settings will be used. Do this, then return to the web console and verify that the "App build specification" section now says "# This project uses an amplify.yml file in the repository root".

Now you can update the amplify.yml file with your custom config.

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - echo ""
        - node -v
        - export NODE_OPTIONS=--max-http-header-size=64555 next dev
        - env | grep -e NEXT_PUBLIC_ >> .env.production
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: .next
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```